# call function multiple times that is linked to async function js

Tags: javascript, csv, asynchronous, fetch

I have two functions, the first one is async one due to the fetch of csv and the second is rendering list of cities. The csv contains data on shops in several cities. On html page I would like to render list of cities and append to them the shops if mouse clicked on the city. My problem right now is that I cannot render list for different city if I have already done it for another one.

```
let arr; 
let shops = [];
let cities = [];


async function getData() {
  let response = await fetch('list.csv', {credentials: 'include'});
  const  data = await response.text();
  arr = data.split('\n');
    
  let headers = arr[0].split(';');
  for(let i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
      let datas = arr[i].split(';');
      let obj = {};
      for(let j = 0; j < datas.length; j++) {
        obj[headers[j]] = datas[j].trim();
      }
    shops.push(obj);
  }


  //group cities
  for (let i = 0; i < shops.length; i++) {
        cities.push(shops[i].IC_GROUP0);
  }

  renderLists();
}

getData();

function renderLists() {

  for (let i = 0; i < cities.length; i++) {
    let listOfCities = document.createElement("LI");
    town = document.createTextNode(cities[i]);
    listOfCities.appendChild(town);
    listOfCities.setAttribute("id", cities[i]);
    document.getElementById("list").appendChild(listOfCities); 
  }

  for (let i = 0; i < cities.length; i++) {
    document.getElementById(cities[i]).onclick = function makeAList() {
      shops = shops.filter(item => item.IC_GROUP0 == cities[i]);
      
      //addresses
      for (let m = 0; m < shops.length; m++) {
        let nodeAddress = document.createElement("P");
    
        //list of shops to HTML
        let address = document.createTextNode(shops[m].IP_PROP303);

        nodeAddress.appendChild(address);
    
        document.getElementById(cities[i]).appendChild(nodeAddress);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain why not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was after "onclick" function. Array shops was rewritten. To solve it I wrote following `let shopsFiltered = shops.filter(item => item.IC_GROUP0 == cities[i]);` and then simply changed at every rendering part `shops[m]...` to `shopsFiltered[m]...`.